# Want to fetch the value from the string

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this.

```
var test = "the email body text is <p>the email test is the email tes is the email.</p>
<p><span id="xXmergefield selnameXx5" class="tag mergefield selname" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.75);" contenteditable="false" **data-replacement="{MERGEFIELD SailName}"**>Sail Name<em id="xXmergefield selnameXx5-remover" class="fas fa-times remover"></em></span></p>"
```

For saving, I want the variable test as,

```
var test = "the email body text is <p>the email test is the email tes is the email.</p>{MERGEFIELD SailName}".
```

Instead of ----

```
<p><span id="xXmergefield selnameXx5" class="tag mergefield selname" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.75);" contenteditable="false" data-replacement="{MERGEFIELD SailName}">Sail Name<em id="xXmergefield selnameXx5-remover" class="fas fa-times remover"></em></span></p>
```

-------- i want the value of the attribute **data-replacement** only - {MERGEFIELD SailName}.

The final result need to be

```
var test = "the email body text is <p>the email test is the email tes is the email.</p>{MERGEFIELD SailName}".
```

Comment: you want to get the value of `data-replacement` ?

Comment: What do you mean by *instead of*? Where is the code that is trying to get the string you are looking for?

Comment: what did you try? And how could you run this without syntax error?

Comment: means....inside the span we have the attribute data-replacement. So I want the value of that attribute instead of full span

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var input = 'the email body text is <p>the email test is the email tes is the email.</p><p><span id="xXmergefield selnameXx5" class="tag mergefield selname" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.75);" contenteditable="false" data-replacement="{MERGEFIELD SailName}">Sail Name<em id="xXmergefield selnameXx5-remover" class="fas fa-times remover"></em></span></p>'

var matches = input.match(/<p><span(.*?)<\/span><\/p>/g);
for(var i=0;i<matches.length;i++){
  var tag = matches[i].match(/data-replacement="(.*?)">/)[1];
  input = input.replace(matches[i],tag);
}

console.log(input);
```

Comment: There are number of <p><span id="xXmergefield selnameXx5" class="tag mergefield selname" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.75);" contenteditable="false" data-replacement="{MERGEFIELD SailName}">Sail Name<em id="xXmergefield selnameXx5-remover" class="fas fa-times remover"></em></span></p> are there. Where ever this span tag coming, i want {MERGEFIELD SailName}...so how to replace the span tag with their corresponding data-replacement=

Comment: Updated the ans. Check it agian